# How do I make this repeat?

Tags: c++

How do I make this repeat the option after the question, for example:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int Hero = 0, Level = 0, Melee = 0, MeleeRanged = 0, Necklace = 0, Charm = 0, Trinket = 0, ItemTotal = 0;
    int choice;
    int Loop = 0;

    
        cout << "Choose the option you want via the menu below: " << endl;
        cout << "1.) Hero Power " << endl;
        cout << "2.)  " << endl;
        cout << "3.) How does Item Power work? " << endl;
        cout << "4.)  " << endl;
        
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:


        {
            cout << "Enter Hero's level: ";
            cin >> Level;

            cout << "Enter Melee's power level: ";
            cin >> Melee;

            cout << "Enter secondary's Melee/Ranged power level: ";
            cin >> MeleeRanged;

            cout << "Enter Necklace's power level: ";
            cin >> Necklace;

            cout << "Enter Charm's power level: ";
            cin >> Charm;

            cout << "Enter Trinket's power level: ";
            cin >> Trinket;

            ItemTotal = Melee + MeleeRanged + Necklace + Charm + Trinket;

            Hero = 10 * Level + ItemTotal / 5;
            
            cout << "Your Hero Power is: " << Hero << endl;
            cout << "Would you like to reselect something in the menu?" << endl;
            cout << "(Y for Yes) (N for No)";
            cin >> choice;
            break;
```

At the end of Case statement 1, 2, 3, and 4 I want to be able to ask a question, have the user type Y or N, and if Y then repeat the menu before to select a new or the same choice. How can I do this?

Comment: `goto` ? That's one bad option :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop. Assuming that you are familiar with loops. But for menu driven programs, `do..while` is better:

```cpp
char ch = 'Y'
do {
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: ..... //your choices
    case 2: .....
    case 3: .....
    default:....
    }
    cout << "Do you want to continue?(Y/N)";
    cin >> ch;
} while (ch != 'N');
```

This menu-driven program will continue until you enter the choice as `N`.

Comment: I need to learn more about loops, they are confusing to me.
 Thank you,  I will study this more.

Comment: I have a new question. 
 This doesn't seem to work correctly, can you tell me why?
```
Do
{
case 3:
cout << "Item Power ranges from 5 to 300." << endl;
cout << " Each time the player opens a chest or crafts an item, the power of the items they get is determined by the average power level of the most powerful items they have found in chests in every item slot." << endl;
cout << "The power of that item will be between[-5 to + 10] over / under that number." << endl;

  } while (Loop != 'N')
```

Comment: Note that you need to accept loop variable within the do{...}while block. From your above comment, I can not see where the "Loop" variable is being changed (or accepted) so that the loop condition(while) is satisfied. If you initialize with some character without changing the variable, it may turn into an infinite loop and crash your program.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Uhm, but what you just said blew my mind. I am very confused about this. I will just study this until I get it I suppose, thank you for your help.